# Bootstrap4 HTML page is too big on mobile

Tags: html, css, django, bootstrap-4

I'm a relative noob with bootstrap and css. I've rebuilt this site from the ground up a couple times in the last couple of weeks to try and sort the spacing etc and currently I have the problem that the main section is slightly too big for a mobile screen in the x dimension and can be scrolled, which is obviously unwanted behaviour. I've tried so many configurations and am so confused as to where this apparent right margin is coming from. (The content fills the screen until you scroll leaving a significant sliver of background body colour.) I've tried debugging by setting the background colour of different elements and the margin shows black with the body background, but white with main, i.e is between the body and the main. I have tried doing this in my css:

```
html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;   // this solves the problem on a small browser window but not on mobile device.
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

main {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #000; // this is what i was referring to that leaves a white margin after scrolling if this color is in the body, the margin is black.
}

main > .container {
  padding-top: 54px;
}
```

in my html I have this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

and all the other required bootstrap and js.

I'm using django framework so the html is in the form of django templates and the base template has the main with navbar:

```
<body>
  <header class="site-header">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-steel fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
    <!-- # Navbar stuff-->
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <main role="main" class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col col-md-10">
        {% if messages %}
          {% for message in messages %}
            <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}">
              {{ message }}
            </div>
          {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
      </div>
    </div>

    {% block content %}{% endblock content %}
  </main>
  <!-- scripts-->
</body>
```

and then the average inner template starts like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col col-md-8">
```

but as I said earlier with the colours the problem doesn't seem to stem beyond the base template. I'm stumped, and *this* close to a complete rebuild but thought I'd try here first!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `col-sm-[1 - 12]`

Comment: You legend! Thank you. You're exactly right, using that in the inner templates works. I did have that on a previous iteration, but had started to believe that the sm settings were default and stopped using them...wrongly! Thank you! Days of puzzling over!

Answer (score 0):

The issue, while fixed in one instance by the other answer, actually stemmed from me having removed the padding on the .container class that I was using on every page. Using the default bootstrap container solved the issue. The cols do in fact default for sm settings as I thought.